# Project won't build with Kotlin 1.1.3

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Android project that I've recently updated with 1.1.3, and every time I build I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReference.<init>(ILjava/lang/Object;)V
```

Other questions typically say that it means that the stdlib is not included, but I have definitely added it. Using `1.1.2-5` works though, and `1.1.3` has worked for other projects.

**Solution**

> The issue was with me mixing the annotation processor with kapt. For
>   projects like DbFlow and Glide, the annotationProcessor dependency can
>   be directly used with kapt.

Back to the original question:

[Here](https://travis-ci.org/AllanWang/Frost-for-Facebook/builds/247284657) is my Travis log and below are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.3-alpha', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile("ca.allanwang:kau:${KAU}")

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:${KOTLIN}"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:${KOTLIN}"

    debugCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:${LEAK_CANARY}"
    releaseTestCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${LEAK_CANARY}"
    releaseCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${LEAK_CANARY}"
    testCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${LEAK_CANARY}"

    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${DBFLOW}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${DBFLOW}"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${DBFLOW}"
    kapt "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${DBFLOW}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-kotlinextensions:${DBFLOW}"

    //Icons
    compile "com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:${IICON_MATERIAL}@aar"
    compile "com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:${IICON_COMMUNITY}@aar"

    compile "org.jsoup:jsoup:${JSOUP}"

    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${GLIDE}"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:${GLIDE}"

    compile("com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:${MATERIAL_DRAWER}@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile "co.zsmb:materialdrawer-kt:${MATERIAL_DRAWER_KT}"

    compile "nz.bradcampbell:paperparcel:${PAPER_PARCEL}"
    compile "nz.bradcampbell:paperparcel-kotlin:${PAPER_PARCEL}"
    kapt "nz.bradcampbell:paperparcel-compiler:${PAPER_PARCEL}"

    compile "com.jude:swipebackhelper:${SWIPE_BACK}"

    compile("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${CRASHLYTICS}@aar") {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Here is the error output when I try building with a full stacktrace: [Removed because this post was too long]
I'm not sure if it helps, but dbflow typically has the warning each build since it does not need to generate the classes every time. I've sent a question to their repo but I don't think that is the issue since it works fine with 1.1.2-5

Edit 2: I had a look at `./gradlew dependencies` and all of them showed kotlin 1.1.3 (too long to post here). There were some that depended on 1.1.0 from their github sources, but that shouldn't be affected and excluding those std-libs did not resolve the error.

Edit 3: Upon trying `.gradlew app:dependencies | grep org.jetbrains.kotlin` I get the following:

```
$ ./gradlew app:dependencies | grep org.jetbrains.kotlin
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.4 -> 1.1.3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.3
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.1 -> 1.1.2-3
|    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3
|    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3 -> 1.1.3 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.1.2-3 (*)
```

Comment: Try to get a stacktrace with --stacktrace as your Travis log suggests.

Comment: What is the gradle version you have used? Once upgrading of gradle to the latest helped me

Comment: @A.Shevchuk I have `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3`, `gradle-3.3-all`

Comment: @Januson I've tried building the source with --full-stacktrace --debug and that I've updated my question with the error output

Comment: LoL, here we go with Kotlin....

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any references to Kotlin 1.0.* anywhere? The reason why I ask is that the `FunctionReference.<init>(ILjava/lang/Object;)V` method that is missing in your case, has appeared in kotlin-stdlib 1.1.0.

Comment: Same happening here :/ I removed any dependencies that had 1.0.* as well

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov This seems to be an error of missing method in kotlin compiler's dependency rather than in a dependency of code being compiled.

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov I looked through the `./gradlew dependencies` output as well as the sources of some of the dependencies and none of them seem to use anything below kotlin 1.1.0

Comment: @AllanW could you also show/inspect the `classpath` dependency configuration of the buildscript?

Comment: @Ilya sorry for the late reply. My classpath contains `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${KOTLIN}"` where the variable points to 1.1.3 (along with my kotlin app dependencies).

Comment: don't mix `annotationProcessor` and `kapt` try using `kapt` only

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In my experience, you:

1. Should not mix `kapt` and `annotationProcessor`
2. Use `kapt3`, by using `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`
3. Do not use `kapt { generateStubs true } }` (it's not allowed with `kapt3`)

Also check whether your Kotlin plugin and your Gradle plugin are up to date.
Additionally I usually don't use the `jre7` version of the standard lib, but I doubt that this is the issue here.

Here is a more exhaustive list of "something with Kotlin doesn't work": https://gist.github.com/lmller/3c43eff454f7508474210fb2491b488a

Comment: You got it with the kapt issue. I'm not sure if anything more needs to be added to use `kapt3`, but just using `kapt` worked for me

Comment: @AllanW if you're using `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` it will use version 3.

Comment: So from this I surmise that you can no longer use kapt2 as of Kotlin 1.1.3, yes? That is how it is working for me right now (and kapt3 isn't working for me because of a bug...)

Comment: @DavidPisoni I don't known if you _can't_ I only know that "my way" works for me

Comment: Understood. Your way is using kapt3 instead of kapt2. Unfortunately, I've found a bug in kapt3 holding me back (that I've reported), where the androidTest package doesn't have generated code from annotation processing (reported here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18895)

Answer (score 2):

the error message reported as:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>
> kotlin.jvm.internal.FunctionReference.<init>(**ILjava/lang/Object;**)V  is **constructor(Int,Object)**

the constructor is introduced in [kotlin 1.1](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/b5ea6d3e25bd296894eff8f63255fba4ee574c42/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/jvm/internal/FunctionReference.java#L30-L34) as below:

```
@SinceKotlin(version = "1.1")
public FunctionReference(int arity, Object receiver) {
    super(receiver);
    this.arity = arity;
}
```

you can run `./gradlew dependencies` and search which dependency uses `kotlin-stdlib` version < `1.1`. and excludes it from your project. something like this below:

```
dependencies{
   compile('which dependency use stdlib < 1.1'){
        exclude group:'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module:'kotlin-stdlib'
   }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question, but I didn't manage to find any dependency below 1.1.0. The gradle log showed all of them as 1.1.3, and from their sources, none of the dependencies seem to use anything under 1.1.0

Comment: @AllanW hi, try to search all of the dependency `org.jetbrains.kotlin` instead.

Comment: @AllanW for example: `./gradlew dependencies | grep org.jetbrains.kotlin | grep -v 1.1.3`

Comment: I ended up just searching for all instances of the word `kotlin`. Nothing shown was under 1.1.0

Comment: @AllanW all of your dependencies are `1.1.3`? you can using my command  to find out which are not `1.1.3`

Comment: actually I just tried again from within the app module and I see some that are under 1.1.0. I've updated my question and I'll figure out which dependencies those are

Comment: @AllanW you try to update `1.1.0` to `1.1.3` and then run your app to see the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147749/discussion-between-allan-w-and-holi-java).

Answer (score 1):

add:

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

[image]